# How to download excel sheet with image in excel js

Tags: javascript, json, excel, exceljs

I'm unable to download excel sheet with images. I am using exceljs. Data is appending correctly but when it comes to image, it is not displaying. I am getting data through json and appending in excel sheet through javascript.

```
var workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Worksheet name');

var imageId2 = workbook.addImage({
  filename: url + 'images/403.png',
  extension: 'png',
});

worksheet.addImage(imageId2, 'H12:N12');

var buff = workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(function(data) {

  var blob = new Blob([data], {
    type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
  });
  saveAs(blob, compname + ".xlsx");
});
```

I cant able to download excel sheet when keeping image code in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a base64 image to make it work:

```
 var myBase64Image = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...";    
 var imageId1 = workbook.addImage({ 
    base64: myBase64Image,
    extension: 'png',
 });
```